# What causes systemctl to show or hide memory or CPU usage of services?

Tags: systemctl

Today morning:

```
# systemctl status udev
? systemd-udevd.service - udev Kernel Device Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-03-13 12:08:58 CET; 5 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-udevd.service(8)
           man:udev(7)
 Main PID: 451 (systemd-udevd)
   Status: "Processing..."
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 4.5M
      CPU: 6.038s
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-udevd.service
           └─451 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
```

Just now (same system - VM with Ubuntu16LTS):

```
# systemctl status udev
? systemd-udevd.service - udev Kernel Device Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-03-13 12:08:58 CET; 5 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-udevd.service(8)
           man:udev(7)
 Main PID: 451 (systemd-udevd)
   Status: "Processing..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-udevd.service
           └─451 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
```

Notice the omission of the `Tasks:`, `Memory:` and `CPU:` lines.
**What has changed here ?** (I did not change anything intentionally ...)

Edit: `ps` output looks unobtrusively:

```
# ps l 451
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
4     0   451     1  20   0  45672  4732 ep_pol Ss   ?          0:01 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
```

I think it has nothing to do with `udev` but rather with `systemd` because I can see the same effect (missing CPU etc.) with other services, too.

Edit #2: `systemctl --version` reports 229.

```
# systemctl show udev | grep Accounting
CPUAccounting=no
BlockIOAccounting=no
MemoryAccounting=no
TasksAccounting=no

# cgmanager
The program 'cgmanager' is currently not installed.
```

Extract of `findmnt` output:

```
/sys/fs/cgroup
├─/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
├─/sys/fs/cgroup/memory
├─/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
├─/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
├─/sys/fs/cgroup/pids
├─/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
├─/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
├─/sys/fs/cgroup/devices
├─/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
├─/sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
└─/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
```

Edit #3:
After a reboot of the VM in question, I'm getting the measurements again while accounting is still disabled:

```
# systemctl show udev | grep Accounting
CPUAccounting=no
BlockIOAccounting=no
MemoryAccounting=no
TasksAccounting=no

# systemctl status udev
...
 Main PID: 444 (systemd-udevd)
   Status: "Processing..."
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 18.9M
      CPU: 4.211s
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-udevd.service
           └─444 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
```

So it doesn't look like those values are generated by the Accounting settings.
Even the global defaults are off:

```
# systemctl show | grep Accounting
DefaultCPUAccounting=no
DefaultBlockIOAccounting=no
DefaultMemoryAccounting=no
DefaultTasksAccounting=no
```

Comment: what state is the process in in `ps`? I wonder if the process is suspended until there is work for the service to do.

Comment: @FrankThomas, I added `ps` output to the question.

Comment: Did you ever found out what caused these differences?

Comment: @gxx, no I didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Memory usage is reported with the `MemoryAccounting=` option, which is enabled by default starting with v238 (unless the distro chooses otherwise) and of course can be enabled by individual units which need to set memory limits. This option uses the "memory" cgroup controller, and appears to work with both v1 and v2 hierarchies.

CPU usage is reported by default starting with v240 on kernel v4.15 and later, if the "unified" (v2-only) cgroup hierarchy is being used. In older versions, it can be enabled using `CPUAccounting=` per unit but has greater impact, as the "CPU" cgroup controller was necessary to obtain this information pre 4.15.

The number of tasks, too, is reported with the `TasksAccounting=` option using the "pids" cgroup controller.

All three functions can be enabled globally (in systemd/system.conf) or per unit. They can be changed on the fly for running services as well. They will of course stop working if other processes (such as cgmanager) meddle with cgroup controller assignments, or if those controllers suddenly disappear from /sys (check `findmnt`), or if pid1 is denied access to them by LSMs (bad idea).

Comment: Added `systemd` version, `findmnt` output and `Accounting` options to the question. Since `/etc/systemd/system.conf` is the default Ubuntu version from 2016 defining all these options to `No`, I cannot explain why these should have been `Yes` several hours before. I checked `journalctl -b` and found `kernel:... timesync vgsvcTimeSyncWorker: Radical host time change` and `systemd...: Time has been changed` because I suspended the VM host (my laptop). Can the time change be the root cause of changed `systemctl` behavior ??

Comment: Updated the question with new information after reboot: While Accounting is still disabled, these measurements are appearing again.